# cahephp formhelper template for generate chekbox

Tags: cakephp, configuration, formhelper

I am using cakephp formhelper and I want to generate checkbox

I want cakephp to generate checkbox like this

```
<div class="form-group form-md-line-input">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label"
           for="form_control_1">checkbox_title</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="md-checkbox-inline">
            <div class="md-checkbox">
                <input id="***this_part_should_be_match"
                       class="md-check"
                       type="checkbox">
                <label for="***this_part_should_be_match">
                    <span></span>
                    <span class="check"></span>
                    <span class="box"></span>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This formhelper config

```
[
    'button'               => '<button{{attrs}}>{{text}}</button>' ,
    'checkbox'             => '<input type="checkbox" name="{{name}}" value="{{value}}"{{attrs}}>' ,
    'checkboxFormGroup'    => '<label class="col-lg-2 control-label">{{label}}</label><div class="col-md-10"> <div class="md-checkbox-list"><div class="md-checkbox"><input id="{{id}}" class="md-check" type="checkbox">
            <label for="{{id}}">
                <span></span>
                <span class="check"></span>
                <span class="box"></span></label></div></div></div>' ,
    'checkboxWrapper'      => '<div class="">{{label}}</div>' ,
    'dateWidget'           => '{{year}}{{month}}{{day}}{{hour}}{{minute}}{{second}}{{meridian}}' ,
    'error'                => '<div class="error-message">{{content}}</div>' ,
    'errorList'            => '<ul>{{content}}</ul>' ,
    'errorItem'            => '<li>{{text}}</li>' ,
    'file'                 => '<input type="file" name="{{name}}"{{attrs}}>' ,
    'fieldset'             => '<fieldset{{attrs}}>{{content}}</fieldset>' ,
    'formStart'            => '<form class="form-horizontal" {{attrs}}><div class="form-body">' ,
    'formEnd'              => '</div> </form>' ,
    'formGroup'            => '{{label}}<div class="col-md-10">{{input}}<div class="form-control-focus"> </div></div>' ,
    'hiddenBlock'          => '<div style="display:none;">{{content}}</div>' ,
    'input'                => '<input class="form-control" type="{{type}}" name="{{name}}"{{attrs}}/>' ,
    'inputSubmit'          => '<input type="{{type}}"{{attrs}}/>' ,
    'inputContainer'       => '<div class="form-group form-md-line-input">{{content}}</div>' ,
    //    'inputContainer'       => '<div class="input {{type}}{{required}}">{{content}}</div>' ,
    'inputContainerError'  => '<div class="input {{type}}{{required}} error">{{content}}{{error}}</div>' ,
    'label'                => '<label class="col-md-2 control-label" {{attrs}}>{{text}}</label>' ,
    'nestingLabel'         => '{{hidden}}<label{{attrs}}>{{input}}{{text}}</label>' ,
    'legend'               => '<legend>{{text}}</legend>' ,
    'multicheckboxTitle'   => '<legend>{{text}}</legend>' ,
    'multicheckboxWrapper' => '<fieldset{{attrs}}>{{content}}</fieldset>' ,
    'option'               => '<option value="{{value}}"{{attrs}}>{{text}}</option>' ,
    'optgroup'             => '<optgroup label="{{label}}"{{attrs}}>{{content}}</optgroup>' ,
    'select'               => '<select class="form-control" name="{{name}}"{{attrs}}>{{content}}</select>' ,
    'selectMultiple'       => '<select name="{{name}}[]" multiple="multiple"{{attrs}}>{{content}}</select>' ,
    'radio'                => '<input type="radio" name="{{name}}" value="{{value}}"{{attrs}}>' ,
    'radioWrapper'         => '{{label}}' ,
    'textarea'             => '<textarea class="form-control" name="{{name}}"{{attrs}}>{{value}}</textarea>' ,
    'submitContainer'      => '<div class="">{{content}}</div>' ,
]
```

And currently it generate this

```
<div class="form-group form-md-line-input">
    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">
        <input class="form-control"
               name="active"
               value="0"
               type="hidden">
        <label for="active">
            <input name="active"
                   value="1"
                   id="active"
                   checked="checked"
                   type="checkbox">
            Active
        </label>
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="md-checkbox-list">
            <div class="md-checkbox">
                <input id=""
                       class="md-check"
                       type="checkbox">
                <label for="">
                    <span></span>
                    <span class="check"></span>
                    <span class="box"></span></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm wondering what should be my config to cakephp generate chekboxes as I want

in the theme I am using id="***this_part_should_be_match" and for="***this_part_should_be_match" should be the same to displays properly

I'm using cakephp 3.5 but I think it should be same in 3.*
I`ll appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the config

```
'checkboxContainer' => '<div class="form-group form-md-line-input"><label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="form_control_1">{{title}}</label>
     <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="md-checkbox-inline">
            <div class="md-checkbox">
                {{content}}{{label}}
                    <span></span>
                    <span class="check"></span>
                    <span class="box"></span>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>'
```

You'll have to set the title with the `templateVars` option when generating the checkbox

```
$this->Form->control('some_checkbox', ['type' => 'checkbox', 'templateVars' => ['title' => 'checkbox_title']);
```